# How to add an enter everytime I use x.innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, string, innerhtml

I'd like to know if it's possible for everytime I'm using an `logger.innerHTML` statement that there would be an "enter" used everytime it detects there's a `logger.innerHTML` in my code, so that every string used with `logger.innerHTML` would start on a new line.
I know that I could add something like `<br>` for the enter, but I forgot to use it in the code beforehand and I don't reaaaally feel like adding an extra `<br>` 79 times in the jungle of code I created for each `logger.innerHTML` (unless there's no solution at all for this problem).

Example for clarification:

```
logger.innerHTML += "hello world!";
logger.innerHTML += "this code has to start on a new line";
logger.innerHTML += "this one too";
```

What code do I need to use here so that every string for `logger.innerHTML` will automatically start on a new line without having to edit every string with `<br>`?

Help would be very much appreciated! Let me know if the question isn't clear enough.

Comment: please describe your question that what you want to do exactly

Comment: Your question is not clear!!! 
Are you saying that you dynamically add text to logger.innerHTML and everytime the text is added it should appear in next line rather than continue?

Comment: The only way you can force it, as far as I know, is to create your own function where you add the passed line plus a newline.

Comment: "*I don't [really] feel like adding an extra `<br>` 79 times in the jungle of code I created*" - then tidy up that code, and organise it more properly and less redundantly. Use this as a learning experience for next time.

Comment: @David Thomas That wasn't the topic of this question. I was searching if some kind of function exists that can add this automatically for each `logger.innerHTML`.

Comment: Yes, I know. But searching for solutions to a problem caused by your own coding conventions is a problem that begets more problems. In this case prevention is far, far better than the cure.

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't really tell what's better in this case beforehand, since I haven't seen the "cure" for it yet at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use some advanced text editor with a 'Find and Replace' and regular expressions (like Notepad++, Kwrite etc) and replace `";` with `<br/>";`

All other methods would require more effort (keystrokes and mouseclicks). That includes replacing every `logger.innerHTML` entry with a `logger()` function.

Comment: downvote: This solution will not lead to better code and (more important) it proposes the wrong replacement. Should be `<br/>";`

Comment: Okay, accepted the part about <br/>. But not about 'better code'. Not everything should be done by writing code, when you have a reasonable much more simple way. Called KISS, you know.

Comment: Using `innerHTML` is not a recommended way to add content. Especially when it's being used in this heavy way. But this is not your fault, so I retire my downvote ;-)

Comment: I don't mind replacing every `logger.innerHTML` with `logger()` so far, as I'm planning to use this a lot more in the future.